# How to understand "as convenient" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And the statement print(f'{num*fraction:,.0f} is {fraction*100}% of {num:,}') prints 15,000,000 is 50.0% of 30,000,000 because the , modifier instructs Python to use commas as thousands separators. We will introduce other modifiers **as convenient** later in the book.

How to understand "as convenient" here? What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that whenever there is a good opportunity to introduce a new concept, we will do so. We won't just bring in new modifiers randomly.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. May I use when to repalce as? Or does as here mean when?

Comment: As means when, yes. The two are interchangeable.